# MS Chart color and legends in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I use a Microsoft Chart in one of my forms. I selected a Pie Chart.

Then, in runtime, I assign the values and legends I need like this:

```
{
    double[] yValues = { valor_pendiente, valor_gest_judicial, valor_cancelado };
    string[] xNames = { "Pendientes", "Gest. Judic.", "Cancelado" };

    chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xNames, yValues);
    Color[] colores = new Color[] { Barra_azul, Color.Orange, Color.LimeGreen };
    chart1.PaletteCustomColors = colores;
}
```

Ok, now I have two questions:

<strike>1: Is there any way to hide the legends when the value is so small or zero? Because graphically, I does not look OK.</strike>

[image]

Gest. Judic. does not have any value there and stills shows.

Is there any other way to show legends?

**1st issue has been solved**

Also, the second question:

Can I Use gradients instead of colors (instead of using that array of colors)? If I can, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Series` class lets you set a `BackGradientStyle` for gradient direction. Then set `BackSecondaryColor` to change the fade-in color of the gradient.

```
chart1.Series[0].BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalRight;
chart1.Series[0].BackSecondaryColor = Color.Cyan;
```

You can also set the gradient for each DataPoint in the chart to give them each a custom gradient:

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[0].BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalRight;
chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Color = Color.Red;
chart1.Series[0].Points[0].BackSecondaryColor = Color.Brown;
```

Note that this doesn't work if you have the 3D effect enabled, so it must be turned off.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
```